# Using OWASP ZAP behind a corporate proxy

Tags: configuration, proxy, owasp, zap

Is there any way to use ZAP behind a corporate proxy? I.e. I want to configure my browser to use the local proxy provided by ZAP, and then ZAP should send the request through our global proxy:

```
Firefox -> ZAP -> WSA proxy (NTLM) -> Intarweb
```

Even if ZAP doesn't support NTLM proxies it would be good to know, as I'm also running CNTLM locally for those applications that can't handle the authentication properly.

(I tried searching for a solution but it's of course impossible to find anything to do with proxies for an application that has "proxy" in the name ... :/ )

Comment: have you tried taking the necessary steps to configure java for using a proxy ?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/issues/detail?id=1633. Did I manage to make the impossible possible ? ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Besides that it should be possible to configure the proxy used by ZAP like you would do for any other Java based application ZAP provides a setting for that: Open `Options` and then `Connection` and specify your proxy settings.

You can read about this here: https://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/issues/detail?id=1633

Comment: Dead Link in source. New proxy documentation is here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/network/options/connection/#http-proxy